# how to localize Russian date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I use gem russian. the following code works:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><%= Russian::strftime(Time.now) %></div>
```

but I need to work the following code:

```
<% @all_diary.each do |diary| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to user_path(diary.id) do %>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.name %></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.created_at.to_time.strftime('%e %b %Y') %></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.updated_at.to_time.strftime('%e %b %Y') %></div>
      <% end %>  
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the date is not displayed localized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the I18n `localize` helper (it has a short alias `l`):

```
<%= l diary.created_at, format: :long %>
```

You can also specify the format explicitly:

```
<%= l diary.created_at, format: "%e %b %Y" %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/localize